# JavaScript NaN Error in IE but not in Firefox, Chrome etc

Tags: javascript

I've got a page where two dates are selected and the inclusive difference between them is displayed in a third text input.

The calculation is made nicely in Firefox, Chrome etc but IE6, IE7 & IE8 a NaN error is displayed.

I've tried parseInt(), number() etc but to no avail.

```
$('#firstday, #lastday').datepicker({
    showOn: 'both',
    buttonImage: 'img/cal.gif',
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    onSelect: function(){
      // Date will give time difference in miliseconds, divide with 1000*60*60*24
      var firstday = new Date($("#firstday").val().split("/").reverse().join(","));
      var lastday = new Date($("#lastday").val().split("/").reverse().join(","));
      // Remove weekend days from count
      var weekend_count = 0;
      for (i = firstday.valueOf(); i <= lastday.valueOf(); i+= 86400000) {
        var temp = new Date(i);
        if (temp.getDay() == 0 || temp.getDay() == 6) {
          weekend_count++;
        }
      }
      var totaldays = ((lastday - firstday) / 86400000) + 1 - weekend_count;
      $('#totaldays').val(parseInt(totaldays)); // parseInt as sometimes, with a long gap between first and last, a decimal number is displayed. Ok, people wont be booking 120 day holidays, but it keeps things proper
    }
  });
```

Comment: How about just posting the *relevant* code here? Maybe IE just does not like to subtract two `Date` objects. Try with their representation in milliseconds.

Comment: Instead of directing people to another site, please post your code here.

Comment: problem is probably in the "date string" for the data that works in firefox but does not in ie.

Comment: You should first check what `lastday - firstday` gives you in IE. I'm not familiar with debugging tools for IE but I'm sure there is a JavaScript console available with which you can test subtracting dates.

Comment: Is it sort of some freelance work that some body has assigned you have posted here? Whether it is or it is not, it is not a problem in asking any thing  but you should atleast tell cleary so that other users can help you easily, it will be more helpful if you will post your code here

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts and ideas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using this wired code `$("#firstday").val()` (that gives you `NaN`) use [getDate](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#method-getDate) method of jquery.ui, that gives you `Date` object. So change

```
var firstday = new Date($("#firstday").val().split("/").reverse().join(","));
var lastday = new Date($("#lastday").val().split("/").reverse().join(","));
```

to

```
var firstday = $("#firstday").datepicker('getDate');
var lastday = $("#lastday").datepicker('getDate');
```

Comment: Yes, fantastic. It's breaking my weekend count though. Any thoughts?

Comment: No it isn't, sorry about that. I'd commented it out and not noticed!